# Find four solutions to $p^2+1=q^2+r^2$ with primes $p$, $q$ and $r$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, sums-of-squares

Q. Find four solutions to $p^2+1=q^2+r^2$ with primes $p$, $q$ and $r$?

My thinking: I think 2(= q or r ) will not satisfy this equation.
Hence we are left with odd prime numbers.
We can factories to to get
(p+q-r-1)(p+r-q-1)=2(qr-p)
Or simply
(p+q)(p-q)=(r+1)(r-1)
But I am not able to make any conclusions.
It's is from {250 problems in elementary number theory}
Q.78 (4.primes and composite numbers)
Please give any hint(theorem that may help)

Comment: $p>\min(r,q)$ might help.

Comment: Hint: The question is asking for FOUR solutions, not to solve the equation. This suggests that trying to solve it is probably very hard, try to FIND 4 solutions.

Comment: There are lots of small solutions, for example $(13, 7, 11), (17, 11, 13), (23, 13, 19), (31, 11, 29), (37, 23, 29), (41, 29, 29)$. But I don't see a systematic approach either.

Comment: @rogerl .See the A by S. Dolan for the case $q=r$. There is a formula for integer solutions to $p^2+1=2q^2$ but not any known system (other than an upward search) for finding all cases with $p,q$ prime. I doubt that it is known whether there are infinitely many such cases.

Answer (score 5):

The question appears to allow $q=r$ and this then requires prime number solutions of Pell's equation $$p^2+1=2q^2$$

For example

$p=7, q=r=5$

$p=41, q=r=29$

Comment: I doubt that it is known whether there are infinitely many such cases with $ p,q$  prime.................+1

Comment: No, I'm sure you are right.

Comment: However, I have refined the other method of solution and it seems to give primes very freely since it only requires linear relationships.

Answer (score 2):

To find **all**  solutions systematically.

All solutions can be generated using primitive Pythagorean triples. Let $(a,b,c)$ be a primitive Pythagorean triple with $b$ even. Then $p,q,r$ form a solution if they are primes such that
$$b=ap-cr,$$
$$bq=cp-ar.$$

**Example** (using the most obvious triple)

We must solve 
$$4=3p-5r,$$
$$4q=5p-3r.$$

Then there is a positive integer $k$ such that $$p=10k+3,q=8k+3,r=6k+1.$$

The relative abundance of these primes can be seen in the screenshot referenced below. (And this is for just one of infinitely many Pythagorean triples.)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOyfD.png

Answer (score 1):

A nice identity could be $$\left(\left(\dfrac{(r-1)}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{(r-1)}{2}+1\right)^2+1=\left(\left(\dfrac{(r-1)}{2}\right)^2+\dfrac{(r-1)}{2}-1\right)^2+r^2$$

Comment: It's not just "could be", it is! This is the most general identity I've seen so far to cover all odd primes by one term.

Answer (score 1):

There can be a solution when $(p^2+1)/2$ is composite. A way to find it by example:

$$13^2+1=170=17\cdot10=(4+i)(4-i)(3+i)(3-i)=\begin{cases}(13+i)(13-i)=13^2+1^2\text{ You know this solution}\\(11+7i)(11-7i)=11^2+7^2\text{ This is the new solution}\end{cases}$$

Alas, not always the other solution is with prime numbers

Comment: If $p^2+1=xy$ where $x\ge y>2$ and each of $x, y$ is a sum of two squares then there exists at least one pair $(q,r)$ with $q\ge r>1$ and $p^2+1=q^2+r^2.$ But $q,r $ may fail to be prime..... +1