# Solve for the prime numbers $x^{2}+1=y^{2}+z^{2}$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

I need find all solutions of the following equation :

$$x^{2}+1=y^{2}+z^{2}...(1)$$

Where : $x,y,z$ are prime numbers

I only found the answer to this problem : $a\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{cases} x=5a+13\\y=3a+7\\z=4a+11\end{cases}$$
My try
Let find some solutions then generalize!

$$(1)\Leftrightarrow (x-z)(x+z)=(y-1)(y+1) $$
Now try for y:

$y=2$ impossible

$y=3$ impossible

$y=5$ impossible

$y=7, z=11 , x=13$

$y=11 $ impossible

How I complete ? And any other simple way!

Can you assist
I'm thankful!

---

Thanks!

Comment: $y = 5$ is not impossible, at least if it is not required that they all be distinct. $7^2 + 1 = 5^2 + 5^2$.

Comment: For general positive integers, the answer you give certainly does not give all solutions.

Comment: Also, $31^2 + 1 = 11^2 + 29^2$, $17^2 + 1 = 11^2 + 13^2$.

Comment: @Ellen Ellen, were did you get this question? At first glance this does not look easy

Comment: Ellen, you asked this 9 months ago: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3429967/determine-all-prime-numbers-p-q-r-such-that-p21-r2q2

Comment: Closely related: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3354241/752069

Comment: You have asked multiple times it seems: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3227349/problems-equation-prime-numbers-p21-q2r2

Comment: There's much more solutions, the first are $(13, 7, 11)
(17, 11, 13)
(31, 11, 29)
(23, 13, 19)
(43, 13, 41)
(73, 17, 71)
(47, 19, 43)
(37, 23, 29)
(47, 23, 41)
(47, 29, 37)
(73, 29, 67)
(107, 29, 103)
(53, 31, 43)
(241, 31, 239)
(67, 41, 53)
(89, 41, 79)
(109, 41, 101)
(421, 41, 419)
(73, 43, 59)
(83, 43, 71)
(157, 43, 151)
(233, 43, 229)
(463, 43, 461)$

Comment: By the way this is not solvable in a way that someone would give you formula for all prime solutions (no such practical formula is known, and it seems there are infinitely many solutions to this), you turned an easy problem (to find 4 solutions) into an impossible problem.

Comment: $3195$ solutions below $50000$, source code [here](https://tinyurl.com/math-3786476)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has already been asked **twice** before by the same OP, moreover without mentionning it. I add that the behavior of this person is not correct towards Maths SE : very few of the good answers to the numerous questions of the OP are accepted (=checked) ; no one in the past months...

Comment: @JeanMarie Is it possible to merge duplicate questions so the answers are at one place?

Comment: @ Dávid Laczkó I don't think so, alas. It is why cross referencing them is so important...

Answer (score 2):

Probably this should be only a comment, but it's too long.
I am not sure, that the condition of primes makes the problem easier or harder, so I am putting that aside. Even in that case, as Sil comments, how could there be a general formula for all solutions?
I tried to come up with another generalisation, one that possibly covers a triple that can not be generated by the OP's formula - and I managed to do that. Based on this one example my question is that can any solution be generalised? I am going to disappoint, because I did not even try with other numbers, just one triple, so I am not providing any answer. But this one example might be interesting and a base for some trials for other triples not covered.
I picked up the triple from Daniel Fischer's comment (31, 11, 29).
A generalisation looks like $a\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{cases} x = \alpha_1 a + \beta_1 \\y = \alpha_2 a + \beta_2 \\z = \alpha_3 a + \beta_3 \end{cases}$$
The original equation this way is
$\alpha_1^2 a^2 + 2 \alpha_1 \beta_1 a + \beta_1^2 + 1 = \alpha_2^2 a^2 + 2 \alpha_2 \beta_2 a + \beta_2^2 + \alpha_3^2 a^2 + 2 \alpha_3 \beta_3 a + \beta_3^2$
$\alpha_1^2 a^2 + 2 \alpha_1 \beta_1 a + \beta_1^2 + 1 = (\alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2) a^2 + 2 (\alpha_2 \beta_2 + \alpha_3 \beta_3) a + \beta_2^2 + \beta_3^2$
Now I want to make the coefficients of the same power of $a$ on the LHS and RHS pairwise equal, so
$\alpha_1^2 = \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2$, so $\alpha$'s must be pithagorean triple,
$2 \alpha_1 \beta_1 = 2 (\alpha_2 \beta_2 + \alpha_3 \beta_3)$, this is what I will solve for $(*)$
$\beta_1^2 + 1 = \beta_2^2 + \beta_3^2$ - this is the original problem, so I will use a solution, and set $\beta_1 = 31, \beta_2 = 11, \beta_3 = 29$
and substituting it into $(*)$ and also simplifying it I get
$31 \alpha_1 = 11 \alpha_2 + 29 \alpha_3$
$\alpha_1 = \frac{11 \alpha_2 + 29 \alpha_3}{31}$
As $\alpha$'s must be pithagorean triple, I substitute it into that equality and get
$(\frac{11 \alpha_2 + 29 \alpha_3}{31})^2 = \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2$
and after transformations and simplifications I get
$319 \alpha_2 \alpha_3 = 60(7 \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2)$
Again, with a pairwise equality logic (and the fact that 319 is not divisible by 60) I want to make
$\alpha_2 \alpha_3 = 60$ and $319 = 7 \alpha_2^2 + \alpha_3^2$
and it is possible with $\alpha_2 = 5, \alpha_3 = 12$
therefore to have a pithagorean triple $\alpha_1 = 13$, and I created a generalisation $a\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\begin{cases} x = 13 a + 31 \\y = 5 a + 11 \\z = 12 a + 29 \end{cases}$$
which was much fun but I do not want to try yet another triple, maybe a journey for someone else, and how often this generalisation produces prime numbers,
I
have
no
i
dea